# add/remove UIViewController inside of uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableview with 3 tableviewcells. 
Every tablecell is 500px height.
I would like to "insert" an uiviewcontroller into the tablecell when I tap on it.

Something like this:

cell 1

cell 2  <== (when I tap on cell 2, new uiviewcontroller "flies" into cell from the right side)

cell 3

I can add ViewController into tablecell like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[myTable viewWithTag:(9000 + [indexPath row])];
MyViewController* myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
...
...
...
[cell.contentView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

but I have problems dismissing my MyViewController. Can someone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create view (from nib file) and load it and display in UItableViewCell but not view controller. But if you wanted control over that custom view, add delegate methods to that custom view and make the tableview controller as delegate to that view. That would work.

Instead you want to go with your idea,

You can write,

`[myVC.view removeFromSuperView];` // you can do some animations here.

Comment: thanks, that is just what I needed - I followed your suggestion and it works.

Answer (score -2):

You cant have a view controller inside a UITableViewCell...

What you have to do is have a UIView instead a UIVIewController.

Comment: It is possible to put a `UIViewController.view` into the content view of a `UITableViewCell` and this can be used to wrap the logic for the cell in the controller itself